# How to Convert String to LocalDateTime

Tags: jodatime

Hi i want to convert the following Date string into LocalDateTime, Can any one explain how to do it.

```
dateString = '21 Oct 2004'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "21 Oct 2004";
LocalDateTime ldt = 
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMM yyyy")
  .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)
  .parseLocalDateTime(input);
System.out.println(ldt); // output: 2004-10-21T00:00:00.000
```

This Joda-Time-code will automatically use midnight at start of day as default value for the missing time component.